# Insert unicode data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I'm using Linq and stored procedures in my asp.net project and when the stored procedure is executed in the code it inserts the characters as `?` although if I execute it outside the code it inserts character correctly!

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_news
(
    @title nvarchar(50),
    @subject nvarchar(MAX),
    @imageurl nvarchar(50),
    @tagid int,
    @adminid int
)
AS
    INSERT INTO news 
    VALUES(@title, @subject, @imageurl, @tagid, @adminid)

    RETURN
```

The `@title` is always inserted correctly.

This is how I call the stored procedure:

```
DS.add_news(txttitle.Text, txtsubject.Text, imgurlLbl.Text, 
            int.Parse(ddltags.SelectedValue), 
            int.Parse(Session["admin_id"].ToString()));
```

I'm confused why `@title` is inserted correctly but `@subject` didn't!

This is the `News` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[news] 
(
    [newsid]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [title]    NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [subject]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [imageurl] NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [tagid]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [adminid]  INT            NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_news] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([newsid] ASC)
);
```

Comment: What are the strings for title and subject which are passed to the stored procedure?

Comment: well it come from textboxes as u can see! ... whatever is typed in the textbox

Comment: languages with Latin letters like English,Spanish, ...etc is fine ,but languages like Arabic,Hendi,Parsian...etc are not!!

Comment: How is your `news` table defined?

Comment: @helb I've updated the question with the table definition

Comment: I quite sure there is nothing wrong with my code ,but where is the problem!! this drives me crazy !

Comment: You are not accidentally inserting into the *other* news table you forgot you created in a different database? Which SQL Server are you using?

Comment: no there is no conflicts with other tables or databases! ... am using sql server 2012 with vs 2013

Comment: I tried to delete the **add_news** sp from the DataClasses and add it again then it worked correctly